# Use one template for different custom post types with the same markup

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I am wondering how I can create one template for multiple custom post types.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Like in an archive.php template?

Comment: Don't get the question right, but maybe this will help. Add a single-$post_type.php for every post type you wan't to have the same "template" for. Then <?php require('path/to/the/real/file.php') ?> in the file.

This will help you visualize the template hierarchy.
http://wphierarchy.com/

Comment: @PieterGoosen, Thnkx I think this is what I searching for. But is the meta registration needed? Because I only want to display all custom post types in the same template.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Hmm I can’t get it work. I have create a new template `page-cpt.php` and add the following to the file: http://snippi.com/s/dz6ja7z

Comment: @PieterGoosen, I think I'm almost there, but maybe you can help me from here. I now get all post type posts listed on a page and not only the posts of that page which is linked to the CPT. Here my template code http://snippi.com/s/ruuujph also I used the following reference of the codex and than the part “ Output a list of all public custom post types " http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types